# Controling compositor by python

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I've been looking at the python code loging of Blender.
But in there things get loged as mouse clicks.

What i like to do is combine a few images into a larger one using compositor, but i need control over compositor by python script. The problem seams to me that it is a bit hard to "spawn" a few nodes, set their values and connect them.

I need an micture of:  image, scale, source image location, mix nodes, output nodes

I have no Code samples other then the log of blender python which in this case is of no big help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A simple code example:

```
# switch on nodes and get reference
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

# clear default nodes
for node in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(node)

# create input image node
image_node = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeImage')
image_node.image = bpy.data.images['YOUR_IMAGE_NAME']
image_node.location = 0,0

# create output node
comp_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeComposite')   
comp_node.location = 400,0

# link nodes
links = tree.links
link = links.new(image_node.outputs[0], comp_node.inputs[0])
```

Here are node types you can create:
[Nodes subclasses API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNode.html)

If you need anything more let me know.

Comment: the code fails me, could you post an example that works ?
i itry to correct it myself but not sure what to type

Comment: This example works for me, what error message do you get?

Comment: Python script fail, look in the console for now. But the console doesnt show anything so i'm puzzled.

Comment: Its the System console: MainMenuBar > Window > ToggleSystemConsole

Comment: Aha it wants to load an image, from the location of the blend file; but it needs to use a fixed set path D:\BlenderTemp\myimage.jpg