# stitching image slices together with python or compositor

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, image

Hi I'm creating 3d panoramic spherical renders and as far as i can tell 2.75 doesn't really support that out of the box. So I found the work around is animating the camera and creating 360, 12px slices.

I'm wondering if there is a python script or node setup I can use to restitch these slices back together (horizontally)? btw- I tried using the program stereo photo maker but it failed to open and stitch my image. Then i started to do it by hand in Photoshop which works fine except  it's ridiculously tedious. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the images do not have lens distortion, you only have to concatenate the images, see this answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20863/how-to-merge-images-into-a-single-strip

Comment: Cycles supports panoramic spherical renders by setting the camera to 'Perspective' and the type to 'Mirrorball'.

Comment: I found that using the program imageMagick was the best and easiest way to stitch images together.