# Blender cycles, apply textures through a python script

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, texturing, scripting

I am trying to apply textures through a python script. I would like to use blender cycles renderer. I thought following [these advices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8698) would be sufficient, but sadly Blender does not show the equivalent python commands when applying manually the procedure. How would you do this ? Or, is it possible to force blender to show the python commands ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some related answers [Cycles - How to add nodes to a material?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5670/2271), [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23446/2271), [Create an image node via code](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24064/2271)

Answer (score 5):

This script does not do any unwrapping. List of available [nodes](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html)

```
import bpy

mat_name = "MyMaterial"
image_path = #...

mat = (bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name) or
       bpy.data.materials.new(mat_name))

mat.use_nodes = True
nt = mat.node_tree
nodes = nt.nodes
links = nt.links

# clear
while(nodes): nodes.remove(nodes[0])

output  = nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")
diffuse = nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse")
texture = nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
uvmap   = nodes.new("ShaderNodeUVMap")

texture.image = bpy.data.images.load(image_path)
uvmap.uv_map = "UV"

links.new( output.inputs['Surface'], diffuse.outputs['BSDF'])
links.new(diffuse.inputs['Color'],   texture.outputs['Color'])
links.new(texture.inputs['Vector'],    uvmap.outputs['UV'])

# distribute nodes along the x axis
for index, node in enumerate((uvmap, texture, diffuse, output)):
    node.location.x = 200.0 * index
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure I fully understand: how to apply the texture to an object? Why doesn't blender show the "python commands" when manipulating textures for the cycles renderer?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `nodes.clear()` instead of looping and removing them? Also, is there a way to auto-layout them after adding them? They're positioned on top of each other otherwise.