# Add nodes to a custom node tree

Tags: python, node-editor, pynodes

I have a custom node tree called MyCustomTreeType. I know that there are scripts to add nodes to the composite and material node trees: [Controling compositor by python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/controling-compositor-by-python)

How can I use this with my custom tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example of the custom PyNode tree includes information about how to add nodes to the menus via `NodeCategory` so i'm going to assume you've got menus working.

(if not: see *TextEditor > Templates > Python > Custom Nodes* )

If you want to add a node via python, it's the same as with shader trees or compositor trees, except you use `data.node_groups`.

```
ng = bpy.data.node_groups['MyNodeTree']
new_node = ng.nodes.new(your_nodes_bl_idname)
new_node.location = (20, 40)
```

Comment: I have thousands of objects for which I need to update their materials' nodes/links using Blender's Python API. I am pretty new to nodes stuff in Cycles and I haven't been able to wrap my head around how I can do that. I wonder, do you know how one can do that? If so, could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101820/how-to-add-shader-nodes-and-corresponding-links-to-transparent-materials-assigne) and see if you can offer a solution?