# Where is the Alpha Convert Node in python?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I do not want my alpha premultiplied when saving images. In blender you can use the compositor [Alpha Convert Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/alpha_convert.html) to convert from Premultiplied to Straight. I can't seem to find this node in the [Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=compositor%20node&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [CompositorNodePremulKey](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNodePremulKey.html#bpy.types.CompositorNodePremulKey)

You can find a complete list of available *compositor node types* here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CompositorNode.html.

```
alpha_convert = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodePremulKey')
alpha_convert.mapping = 'PREMUL_TO_STRAIGHT'
```

However, sometimes it's pretty hard to figure out since the names doesn't really match. I'd suggest create the node in the compositor *by hand* and print its [`type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.type) to the console to get an idea:

```
import bpy

class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        space = context.space_data
        node_tree = space.node_tree
        node_active = context.active_node
        
        print (node_active.type)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*Or* use `Node.bl_rna` attribute which returns the actual struct (to copy the name from):

```
>>> node_active.bl_rna
<bpy_struct, Struct("CompositorNodePremulKey")>
```

**Related: [Controling compositor by python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19500)**